# nginx reverse proxy configuration for docker

Tags: docker, http, nginx

I am having hard time figuring out configuration to load locally running dockerised web app in the domain.

Below are:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  ui:
    build: ./ui
    volumes:
      - ./ui:/app/sr
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    networks:
      - webnet
    links:
      - api
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    container_name: api
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

**nginx/conf.d/ui.example.conf**

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen [::]:80;

server_name ui.example.de www.ui.example.de;

location / {
proxy_pass http://ui:4200/;
#proxy_buffering off;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

It runs on local machine under the ip
http://138.246.XXX.XX:4200 as well as in http://138.246.XXX.XX
But when I try to access through the web with http://ui.example.com, it gives Error 503.

[image]

I also tried with ip from docker network and my machine ip i.e. http://138.246.XXX.XX:4200 in proxy pass in ui.example.conf.

**[NOTE]:** I removed default from nginx/sites_enabled. Now that is empty as I am only trying for reverse proxy with nginx.
Does anyone have any idea, what am I missing here?

Comment: the nginx is on the host?

Comment: You're missing the "root" parameter for the location, have you specified the server  ui for the address  http://ui:4200/ in nginx config? Could you substitute <ui> with the destination IP address?

Comment: @Stefano , yes, nginx is on the host. web service is in docker container.

Comment: @Andrea, yes, I tried with docker ip on which ui container is running. but it did not work. I replace ui with ip 172.18.0.3:4200, which is my docker network ip.

Comment: did you also try with `localhost:4200`?

Comment: @Stefano, did you mean trying localhost:4200 in proxypass??

Comment: yep, just for testing. otherwise another option would be to try and see if it works when dockerizing the nginx.

Comment: Just now, I tried with localhost:4200 and 127.0.0.1:4200. It did not work.

Comment: I have also tried dockerizing nginx and there it was not able to connect with UI. Actually, It used to work with the above setup, but then there are some modification or missing links which I don't know, causing the problem.

I saw these errors a lot in /var/log/nginx/error.log file:  host not found in upstream "ui" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ui.example.conf:8

Comment: @Jyotirmay can you access the site using <localhost>:4200 from the same machine, without proxy?

Comment: @Andrea, yes. I can.

Comment: @Jyotirmay set `listen 80 default_server;` on nginx and `proxy_pass: http://localhost:4200;` test and reload configuration, it's possible that having set a server name the call is ignored if you're not using a valid dns name

Comment: another suggestion concerning the dockerized solution: avoid using the `links` block and use `depends_on`

Comment: www.<dns> is not resolved, but quicknat.ai-med.de does refer to the machine you're using with container or another computer? I mean, it's the same machine exposed on internet or do you have router or something else in front of it?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think there is a router.@Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Try ELB health checker status by connecting container

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).